# How can I call multiple libraries within python then wait for all to load before moving on?

Tags: python

I want to call multiple functions/libraries and then wait until they all complete before moving forward. For example:

```
import library1
import library2
..
var1 = library1()
var2 = library2()

#I need the above to complete before moving forward to below:
var3 = var1 + var2
```

I've been researching this on SO and I haven't found exactly what I'm looking for, they seem to be multiprocessing the same function with different parameters. I have a process where I download 10 fairly large datasets and by them being sequentially loaded it's taking more time. I'm thinking if I can process all data loads at the same time, it would cut my functions time by a large amount.

Is this possible? Would I use async or multiprocessing for this?

Update - I want var1 and var2 to not block each other. Is there a way for each to load/download before I do something with both of them(Var3) later?

Comment: What are the types of `var1` and `var2`? How exactly do `library1` and `library2` run asynchronously? Do they return coroutines, use multithreading, use multiprocessing, etc?

Comment: Python already behaves this way, what have you actually tried which doesn't work?

Comment: What exactly are you loading?

Comment: Hey everyone, I'll update the question but I'm hoping to have var1 and var2 populated in parallel before I do something with both. I'm asking how can var1/2 be ran async

Comment: @kingkupps In this case, I'm calling a external api and getting a pandas dataframe for each. The libraries are made by me and they just wrap a python requests call to a endpoint then convert a json to pandas. I hope that helps clarify.

Comment: @ti7 the above code is sudo code version of exactly what I'm doing and I can confirm var2 is not being called until var1 is completed. I see this when I look at the logs of the API calls those libraries are making externally.

Comment: It would also help to know which libraries you're using specifically. It sounds like both are using synchronous network I/O based on what you've said so far but just want to confirm.

Comment: @kingkupps these libraries are not public..they are build by me. Simple libraries I made to get different types of data. They are basically requests to external apis then converting to pandas dataframe. But they are different endpoints for different datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a synchronous networking library, like `requests` for example, then using `ThreadPoolExecutor` is a solid option.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def first():
  print('first ran')
  return 1


def second():
  print('second ran')
  return 2


def main():
  with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    f = executor.submit(first)
    s = executor.submit(second)

  print('first and second should have ran by now')
  print(f.result(), s.result())


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Output:

```
first ran
second ran
first and second should have ran by now
1 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Just to confirm, f and s will run together..or if I have 10 items there then they will run based on the max workers then only once the slowest item is done loading it moves on to the print statements?

Comment: You would want to set `max_workers` to the number of tasks you want to run concurrently. The details are summarized nicely [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor). There should be guidelines there with respect to how many workers is too many as well.

Comment: I tried to replace your command with - var1 = executor.submit(library1(ticker)) and I'm expecting a dataframe but got type error. I got a error when I added results() as well.

Comment: You should do `executor.submit(library1, ticker)` instead. The first argument should be a callable and the remaining arguments get passed to the callable when it gets scheduled.